# accessing the next 10 items pagination firestore Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to implement pagination using the admin sdk for firestore, I have limited my query to the 10 most recently created jobs, I would like in theory to have a button a user may select that will display the next ten until they reach however many total jobs they have created for my application.  Currently, I am hitting the end point I have created using the Admin SDK (written in NodeJS) and I only have access to the first 10. I am using react on the front end and am simply hitting the cloud function I created in a fetch to grab the jobs.  What do I need to add to my cloud function so I can request the next ten all the way up until the user can see all of their jobs. I am very lost at this point trying to implement pagination using the Admin SDK any and all help would really be appreaciated my cloud function is as follows:

```
exports.getAuthenticatedUser = (req, res) => {
  let userData = {}
  db.doc(`users/${req.user.uid}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        userData.user = doc.data()
        return db
          .collection("jobs")
          .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid)
          .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
          .limit(10)
          .get()
      } else {
        return res.status(404).json({ errror: "User not found" })
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      userData.jobs = []
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        userData.jobs.push({
          userId: doc.data().userId,
          company: doc.data().company,
          position: doc.data().position,
          status: doc.data().status,
          link: doc.data().link,
          createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
          jobId: doc.id,
        })
      })
      return res.json(userData)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code })
    })
}
```

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation on pagination.  If you are stuck using the API as documented, please edit the question to be more specific. You will need to tell the next query where to start in the results.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: @DougStevenson That's what I'm stuck with I am having trouble with how to dynamically tell firestore where to start the next query.  There are a lot of users with their own jobs, so I'm unsure of how to go about this

Comment: Seems like you will want the client to tell the server where to start the next page by passing a parameter.

Comment: @DougStevenson My client is pure react. is there a way to do this server side?

Comment: @DougStevenson kinda lost and unsure of what I need to do if I'm being honest